# Detecting the state of an in app purchase

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

How can an app check the state of an in app purchase and see whether is has been purchased or not?

I want to do this in the viewWillAppear and set the icons of the in app purchases according to whether they are purchased or not.

Can this be done with the apple libraries?

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2797/introduction-to-in-app-purchases) is a great tutorial which shows you all the steps in setting up in app purchases, including sample code on how to do it. Hope that Helps!